# I've been using parse for my Android App, I need to reset password for other users who forgot their password. How to do that?

Tags: android, parse-platform, passwords, reset

I have been using Parse (buddy) for my Android app as backend and database.
We have scenario where users forget their password and sends reset request.
Apart from doing it manually, is there any code to do that.

I've tried to reset for other user, but I get user not authenticated error?

Comment: I think if you integrate Mailgun then this should facilitate forgot user password/verifying email address functionailty. I haven't done it myself but I think these features are there by default.

Comment: thanks for suggestion.